# HIGHCHARTS POINTSTART TODAYS DATE

Tags: json, django, highcharts

Hi I am using a line chart from Highchart, can you please help me get the x-axis to show present month LAST on the x-axis - and the X-axis to automatically populate going back however many numbers of months it requires for the date. The date is monthly, so for example below installation has 8 points of data I would like it to show December as the 8th point on the X-axis and April as the first. I don't, however, want it to be limited to 8 months, and ideally would like for it to go to 18 months.

Many thanks for reading the long essay.. :)!

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

Comment: We can't do much if you will only provide the properties of your chart. Show us relevant code from your ```views.py``` so we know how you're processing/handling data that you pass onto the chart.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, It's simply passing the name and data as above {
    ``name: 'Installation',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
} ``

Answer (score 0):

As I understood - you would like to start the first point with the date of the first of the December and get point intervals as a day time. Here is a guideline how to achieve it:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        label: {
            connectorAllowed: false
        },
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2019, 11, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day        
        }
},
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fcbn5heo/1/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointStart

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointInterval

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: cheers, is it possible to use the current month ( ie it updates automatically) instead of fixed start point? cheers, I was also looking to display it in reverse and months only, so for example, 6 data points today ( December month) would be last, so the chart would show june, july, august, .... december last - but next month it shows july......jan, and updates based on date today

Comment: Something like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jco0swtf/ ?